# NodeJS Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a syntax error at my async function. There are 2 async functions, 1 works fine but the other has error. Everything works just fine when I serve it, but when deploys there's this error:

[image: error]

Please help me.

The version of my Node is **v8.11.3**

```
global.database = firebase.database()
global.auth= firebase.auth()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    getReady().then(() => {
        next()
    })
})

async function getReady() {
    await auth.signInAnonymously()
    await database.ref('Users').once('value', data => {
        users = data.val()
    })
}

app.listen(8000)

exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Nobody can help you with a syntax error without seeing the code that contains the error. Please edit your question to include a minimal amount of code that reproduces the error.

Comment: *"there's this error"* Which error?

Comment: Do you have error message and/or stacktace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this error, that's because firebase functions expect version 6 of node. You can either transform the async/await with callback or upgrade the version of node to 8. To do so, here are the [steps](https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc):

- Upgrade your firebase-functions version to 2.0.0
- Upgrade firebase-tools to 4.0.0
- Add `"engines": { "node": "8" }` to your `/functions/package.json`

Moreover, I suggest you to follow [Call functions via HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) if you want to make requests from firebase as you didn't specify a route for your request and listen shouldn't be present.